# Unauthorized error while trying to intercept Retrofit request

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

I am using Retrofit below 2.0 in order to make API call.
The endpoint is "http://api.themoviedb.org/3".
The method is

```
@GET("/discover/movie")
void getMovies(Callback<MoviesResponse> callback);
```

They want me to add api_key as parameter. You can see the instructions [here](http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#reference/discover/discovermovie/get).

I am creating interceptor and setting it while building the client.
This is the overridden method of the interceptor.

```
@Override
public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
    request.addHeader("api_key", MY_API_KEY);
}
```

For some reason I get Unauthorized error.
"Invalid API key: You must be granted a valid key."

The example they are giving is:

```
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=###
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was wrong. I was adding a header while they were asking for parameter.

```
@Override
public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
    request.addQueryParam(HEADER_NAME, mApiKey);
}
```